# Is a null reference an instance of a class?

Tags: java, reference, null, instance

This is a simple code

```
class Foo {
}

class Bar extends Foo {
}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    fn(null);
}

static void fn(Foo f) {
    System.out.println(f instanceof Foo ? "Foo" : "Bar");
}
}
```

My question is: How Java knows that the passed null is `Bar` and not `Foo`?
I know why the compiler chooses Bar and not Foo (because there is a conversion from foo to bar and from bar to foo and not vice-versa).
But how would the method know this null comes from Bar and not Foo?
does null contain some information about the object which is assigned to?

Comment: Null cannot be Bar or Foo. It is null.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're reading it the wrong way. `instanceof` *always* evaluates to `false` for `null` references.

From the [Java specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.20.2) (emphasis mine):

> At run time, the result of the instanceof operator is true **if the value of the RelationalExpression is not null** and the reference could be cast (§15.16) to the ReferenceType without raising a ClassCastException. Otherwise the result is false.

Comment: Maybe more because `null` is no instance. However null can be assigned to every class.

Answer (score 1):

It is always false. Javac Knows it.

But you can use f.someStaticFunctionOfTheClassFoo(). So, your question is very interesting, only it needs to be edited.

Comment: I don't see how mentioning static methods is useful here.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by

> How java knows that this null is Bar and not Foo?

`null` is neither `Bar` nor `Foo`. See [Java method dispatch with null argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377203/java-method-dispatch-with-null-argument/377238#377238)

Answer (score 1):

> Is a null reference an instance of a class?

Let's be clear about this. A reference isn't an instance of anything. It is a reference. The *object it refers to*, if any, is an instance of some class. But the null reference doesn't refer to any object.

> My question is: How Java knows that the passed null is Bar and not Foo?

It doesn't. Your program lied to you. It prints "Bar" if the reference *doesn't* refer to an instance of Foo. Poor coding on your part.

> I know why the compiler chooses Bar and not Foo (because there is a conversion from foo to bar and from bar to foo and not vice-versa).

The compiler didn't mkae any such choice. Your code did a poorly designed test and print.

> But how would the method know this null comes from Bar and not Foo?

It doesn't. It guessed. It got it wrong.

> does null contain some information about the object which is assigned to?

It contains no information at all.

Comment: It turned out that I was an idiot when I asked this question :)

Comment: @SleimanJneidi I won't be so churlish as to agree, but it's always good to be able to acknowledge your own errors.

Answer (score 0):

null is a special type and that special type is "NullType".