# Method calling in java

Tags: java

I have the following structure of my class:

```
void add(String s){
    System.out.println("string");
}

void add(Object s){
    System.out.println("object");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyClazz().add(null);
}
```

O/P : `string`

Why object is not called?

Comment: [So](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1572322/1393766) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13133177/1393766) [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5229809/1393766).

Comment: you may find more using https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+overload+method+call+null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` is more specific than `Object`. Therefore `void add(String s)` is preferred over `void add(Object s)`.

> [15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)
>
> The second step searches the type determined in the previous step for
>   member methods. This step uses the name of the method and the argument
>   expressions to locate methods that are both accessible and applicable,
>   that is, declarations that can be correctly invoked on the given
>   arguments.
>
> There may be more than one such method, in which case the most
>   specific one is chosen. **The descriptor (signature plus return type) of
>   the most specific method** is the one used at run time to perform the
>   method dispatch.

Comment: Thanks..Any document referencing the same..