# What does this program do?

Tags: java

An interviewer asked me to explain this code. What does it do?

```
public class Test {
    public void methodOne(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("Object as Parameter");
    }

    public void methodOne(String str) {
        System.out.println("String as parameter");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.methodOne(new Object());
        t.methodOne("");
        t.methodOne(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, for how frequently this seems to show up in interview questions I could never quite figure out why this would be useful.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an interview question and not a real programming issue you are facing.

Comment: I'm not sure about his intention here. But I wanted to know how the JVM will behaves here!!!

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: I'm getting the output like this    
Object as Parameter
String as parameter
String as parameter

then I tried to add another method 

public void methodOne(Integer str){
  System.out.println("Integer as parameter");
 }

here, when I'm calling the method with null parameter I'm getting compilation error
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

My question here is, why I'm not getting same compilation error for my first program?

Comment: It should take about 5 seconds to find out by running the program...

Comment: I'm thinking "it's a trap" because the code looks trivially easy to be a serious question on an interview.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method Overloading for NULL parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-parameter) and [Using null in overloaded methods in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041042/using-null-in-overloaded-methods-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

And:

```
$ javac Test.java 
$ java Test
Object as Parameter
String as parameter
String as parameter
```