# Java: Overload method, what happens with method(null)?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java method dispatch with null argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377203/java-method-dispatch-with-null-argument)

Why does this print "a(String)"?

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        a(null);
    }
    public static void a(Object x){
        System.out.println("a(Object)");
    }
    public static void a(String x){
        System.out.println("a(String)");
    }
    public static void a(int x){
        System.out.println("a(int)");
    }
    public static void a(){
        System.out.println("a()");
    }
}
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_04-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-ea-b228)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: For more surprise, try it with `Integer` and `String` parameter.

Comment: Compilation errors:  reference to a is ambiguous, both method a(String) in Test and method a(Integer)

Answer (score 2):

Because the rule is to select the most specific method and String inherits from Object.

[From the specification :](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)

> If several applicable methods have been identified during one of the
>   three phases of applicability testing, then the most specific one is
>   chosen

Answer (score 1):

In case of overloaded methods compiler calls the method with  **most specific argument**. As `java.lang.String` is more **specific class** than `java.lang.Object` compiler call's the method with string as argument.

From [**Java language Specification:**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)

> If several applicable methods have been identified during one of the
>   three phases of applicability testing, then the most specific one is
>   chosen